# iterator returning random letters can't get it to iterate

Tags: java, iterator, while-loop

I have this iterator,

```
Set<BigFraction> key = knowledgeD.keySet();
    TreeSet<BigFraction> sortKey = new TreeSet<BigFraction>();
        sortKey.addAll(key);

    Iterator<BigFraction> iter = sortKey.iterator();
        return iter;
```

BigFraction is just the data type if it makes it any easier just sub this with int or something.

Anyway when i called the iterator later on to

```
while (iterator().hasNext());
```

It basically just gives me an infinite loop of somesort... and when i printout iterator() before this while loop i get

```
java.util.TreeMap$KeyIterator@53b4b24d
```

Any idea's kind of stuck,

Regards,

Sim

Comment: It should be `iterator.hasNext()`... do you ever call `iterator.next()` (which is what advances the counter to the next object and possibly allows it to be exhausted)?

Comment: @PaulProgrammer no iterator.hasNext() doesn't work for this while loop its throwing an error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use your `Iterator` like this:-

```
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(iter.next()); //Do whatever you want
}
```

where `hasNext()` tells if the `iterator` has more values or not, and `next()` returns the next value in the iterator.

Also, the explanation of why your current `iterator` loop is not working(going into an infinite loop), has been explained by **@jacobm**.

Comment: @Sim - This is just the way how to use an `Iterator`. You need to use it wherever is required for you. Probably, the calling method has some other variable name for the `iterator`. Do check that.

Answer (score 4):

`iterator().hasNext()` never advances the iterator, it just checks to see if it has an element. So `while (iterator().hasNext());` will always infinite-loop if there are any values to iterate over. You can fix it with:

```
Iterator<BigFraction> it = iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
  it.next();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The call to iterator() constructs a new iterator, so your code will construct a new iterator each time through the loop. Instead try something like:

```
Iterator it = iter;
while (it.hasNext()) {
    it.next()
}
```

Be sure to call `next()` each time through the loop, otherwise you won't increment the iterator, and it will just stay on the first item.

Comment: crap now i'm just getting all the values the same in the iterator, i guess its working just my method must be faulty, thanks

Answer (score 1):

`Iterator#hasNext` returns true if the iteration has more elements, it does not return the next element in the iteration. which `Iterator#next` does.

**If you use itarator if you must call `iterator#next` to get the next element of collection, but `hasNext` is operation is optional**.

you could either write -

```
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Object oj = iter.next();
}
```

or

```
Object obj = null;
while ( (obj = iter.next())!=null) {
    ....
}
```

with this approach `hashNext` is not at all required.